# How to reproduce "2 No such file or directory" in C

Tags: c, exception, arguments

I know it might sound strange but I'm trying to find when to get this type of error when passing a wrong argument to a main program.

Let's say I have a program that accepts 1 or 2 arguments. If it's 2 arguments it can only be:

```
argv[0] =./programName
```

and

```
argv[1] = "-A".
```

Any other argv[1] other than "-A" needs to printf a "2 No such file or directory" message.

As far as I know, this is a system message, so printing it will not work for me.

DO I need to save all possible main arguments in a file and then compare the typed arguments with the ones in the file?

Right now the way I have it is:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/times.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
.....
...

if (argc == 2 && strcmp(argv[1], ARGV_2)!=0){
return(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

...
.....
}
```

Comment: *Why* can't you print it? The code excerpt you show looks almost good, but is simply missing the printout. And no there's no "system messages" in the C standard. I also say that the code looks *almost* good, because you have a logical error: Try adding more than one argument when executing your program.

Comment: `fprintf(stderr, "My error message here.\n");`

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>`, `#include <string.h>`, `#include <errno.h>`, `printf("%s", strerror(ENOENT));`.

Comment: A system message of what system?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Apparently should be a system message rather than a n error printf message. The exerpt I've done works perfectly but will not print by default any message. All I want to know if a message such as "No such file or directory" it's only related to file/directories fails which in that case it's very likely that I'll have to store the possible arguments in a file to compare it with.

Comment: if I do `ls [bogusFileName]` I get `ls: cannot access [bogusFileName]: No such file or directory` .. is that what you want? That's the application `ls` printing that error message from the userspace/application level. If you search through its source code you'll find an `fprintf` of that message or something very similar. That's not a message that comes from the OS.

Comment: @n.m. Operating system in my case Ubuntu

Comment: @yano No, just searching in which cases I would get a message like that when typing a wrong argv[1] to execute a program.

Comment: @krm I don't understand what you want. What's wrong with yano's approach of inserting  `fprintf(stderr, "No such file or directory\n");`  right before `return(EXIT_FAILURE);`?

Comment: @yLaguardia Nothing wrong, not allowed to do so, that's all. Assignment norms.

Comment: ohh, got it. Bet I'm wrong about `ls` source code then, it probably does something like this.

Comment: @IanAbbott That one works, still to confirm if it could be a correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think `ls` does this with the `error()` function:

> [GNU Error_messages](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html)
>
> Function: **void error (int status, int errnum, const char *format, …)**
>
> Preliminary: | MT-Safe locale | AS-Unsafe corrupt heap i18n | AC-Safe
>   | See POSIX Safety Concepts.
>
> The error function can be used to report general problems during
>   program execution. The format argument is a format string just like
>   those given to the printf family of functions. The arguments required
>   for the format can follow the format parameter. Just like perror,
>   error also can report an error code in textual form. But unlike perror
>   the error value is explicitly passed to the function in the errnum
>   parameter. This eliminates the problem mentioned above that the error
>   reporting function must be called immediately after the function
>   causing the error since otherwise errno might have a different value.
>
> error prints first the program name. If the application defined a
>   global variable error_print_progname and points it to a function this
>   function will be called to print the program name. Otherwise the
>   string from the global variable program_name is used. The program name
>   is followed by a colon and a space which in turn is followed by the
>   output produced by the format string. If the errnum parameter is
>   non-zero the format string output is followed by a colon and a space,
>   followed by the error message for the error code errnum. In any case
>   is the output terminated with a newline.
>
> The output is directed to the stderr stream. If the stderr wasn’t
>   oriented before the call it will be narrow-oriented afterwards.
>
> The function will return unless the status parameter has a non-zero
>   value. In this case the function will call exit with the status value
>   for its parameter and therefore never return. If error returns, the
>   global variable error_message_count is incremented by one to keep
>   track of the number of errors reported.

So maybe something like this would achieve OP's goal as well as the other answers suggested before:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <error.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2 && strcmp(argv[1], "-A") != 0) {
        error(ENOENT, ENOENT, "cannot access %s", argv[1]);
    }

    printf("program didn't get to here\n");
}
```

Outputs of `ls` and this example:

```
~/workspace/tests/ $ ./ctest bogus_dir
./ctest: cannot access bogus_dir: No such file or directory
~/workspace/tests/ $ ls bogus_dir
ls: cannot access bogus_dir: No such file or directory
```